# How to give OpenVPN profile files to users via the HTTPS?

Tags: vpn, web-server, openvpn, https, apache2

I'm using Mikrotik Router as an OpenVPN server and I want to give the profile file to the users with HTTPS URL so they can import the file using URL in OpenVPN application on Android or IOS phones.
But I have this message when I'm trying to import a profile:
`Selected file has incorrect profile configuration`

The file has the correct configuration. I can use it when I import it from My file.
And this is the log file in the apache web server:

access.log:

> 10.1.2.2 - - [25/Jan/2021:07:37:53 +0000] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 404 1933 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; SM-J610F Build/QP1A.190711.020)"

I know `404` means not found but I just copy and paste from the link of the file in a browser.
I'm currently using an HTTPS server to download the profile file. Then I open this file with OpenVPN application.